# Change Package Name of a a Published Android App

Tags: android, google-play

I recently purchased a published Android App, As part of the ownership transfer the App is currently unpublished. I am ready to re-publish the app, but it still have the package name of the original developer. Should I or can I change this package name to mine and how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can change the package name as it link to the product. If you want to change, you will need to create new product within play store admin page. But, by doing so, you will lose previous download activity.

Taken from [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/06/things-that-cannot-change.html):

> Once you publish your application under its manifest package name,
>   this is the unique identity of the application forever more. Switching
>   to a different name results in an entirely new application, one that
>   can’t be installed as an update to the existing application.

Comment: Thanks, but I am just wondering, does the uniqueness of package name means anything. In other words does it matter that you have an app that have someone's package name?

Comment: as link above stated `this is the unique identity of the application forever more` -> this means every app have unique package name. You can try it by yourself by uploading app with same package name, to see it went through.

Comment: Package name have no impact on anything. Stick with existing package and do not worry about it. If you want to make future changes be sure to obtain also signing certificate. Package and certificate must not be changed!